# My SSD is being seen in the BIOS but not in windows (10) explorer or diskmanagement

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bios

I just got an SSD and am trying to get it to work but for some reason I am not able to format it. When using the `diskpart` command and typing `list disk` this is what I see:

[image]

Only one disk, my current HDD. But when I go to system management and look at stations, my SSD shows up:

[image]

I've tried different cables (a white sata 6g cable and an orange awm cable) but they all have the same result: shown in BIOS but not able to format it in windows 10.

I also tried reinstalling the IDE/ATA/ATAPI controllers because someone said it might work, still nothing. Using a third party partition tool also only shows my 500gb HDD.

What can I do?

Disk management screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried going to Disk Management and formatting the SSD there?

Comment: @NiallUK It doesn't show up there. Only in devicemanagement.

Comment: What motherboard do you have?

Comment: @NiallUK I got the: asus z170 pro gaming motherboard

Comment: A screenshot of disk management please.

Comment: @Moab I added the screenshot

Comment: If you can on that same PC install W7 and see if it recognizes it, W10 is so full of bugs I dont trust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on another forum. Apparently the SSD could be found in `manage storage spaces` inside the configuration. For some reason I had to remove it entirely from there, when I did that the SSD showed up in my disk management.

Very strange but it worked.

This is where I removed the SSD:

[image]